# Display UserControl as popup window

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, dialog

I have a UserControl where I have some buttons and textboxes. I was wondering how I can display that UserControl when a user clicks a button.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Is this winforms? Webforms? WPF? Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Please at least mention which technology you are working on..

Comment: Sorry guys, Iam using winforms. I want show the usercontrol when the user clicks a button. I havent tried anything yet. Sorry again for the lousy question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A user control cannot be a 'popup window', that requires a toplevel window.  A form.  You can put the user control in a form and use the form's Show() method to make it visible.

Fwiw, turning a user control into a toplevel window is technically possible with the SetTopLevel() method.  It isn't worth the hassle, it won't behave like a proper one.

Comment: Showing a usual form can I do. I just wanted to try if there is any way to show the usercontroll instead of a usual form.

Comment: Asked and answered, last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should paste the user control on a windows form and then make it a modal window.  Make a object of that form and then call `object.open();`